# pyside - Is there a way of getting log information for every event in the event loop?

Tags: events, logging, pyside, event-loop, qeventloop

I'm developing an application with PySide, and I was wondering if there is a way of logging which events enter the main event loop and which ones leave. my application use **no threads**, it is complete asynchronous, but I wanted to have log registries of the event loop for debugging purpose. I use `logging` as my logging facility (duh).

Pax et bonum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a good [user on reddit replies](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/20yq3i/pyside_is_there_a_way_of_getting_log_information/cg8srdt):

Check this out: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#notify. The event loop is implemented in QCoreApplication, so you can subclass and install your own code to inspect events.

class Application(QApplication):
    events = {constant: name for name,constant in QEvent.**dict**.items() 
              if name[0].isupper() and isinstance(constant, int)}

```
def notify(self, obj, event):
    print("{:<20}{}".format(Application.events[event.type()], obj))
    return super().notify(obj, event)
```

Works pretty well. https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Z46.png

Of course, you will still have to work out which events are being consumed. That super call returns `True` or `False`, but almost every event I saw was returning `True`. Your might have to traverse object relationships or something—I'm not sure because I haven't done this, but there appears to be pretty good support for getting down into that loop and doing what you like.

---

However, I'm more inclined to follow the third option listed on [Qt's documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#notify):

> 3. Installing an event filter on `QCoreApplication::instance()`. Such an event filter is able to process all events for all widgets, so it's just as powerful as reimplementing `notify()`; furthermore, it's possible to have more than one application-global event filter. Global event filters even see mouse events for disabled widgets. Note that application event filters are only called for objects that live in the main thread.